# Cuándo usar "usar" o "utilizar"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, sinónimos

## Español

Ambos términos tienen un significado muy parecido. Según la RAE, el único uso de 'utilizar' es "Aprovecharse de algo" y el significado que me interesa de 'usar' es "Hacer servir una cosa para algo".

Normalmente, cuando tengo alguna duda con las diferencias sutiles entre dos sinónimos recurro a google, pero en este caso no ha funcionado. Ni la RAE ni otros diccionarios online me han podido ayudar.

La frase de la que me ha surgido la duda es:

> "[...] El nombre del archivo utilizado para este procedimiento es: hallarpi.m"

**¿Es esta opción la correcta o debería de haber utilizado la palabra 'usado'?**

He deducido que es 'utilizado' por pura intuición. Agradecería si alguien me pudiera aclarar la diferencia entre ambos en este contexto.

---

## English

Both terms have a really similar meaning. According to the RAE, the only use for 'utilizar' is "Aprovecharse de algo" and the meaning which concerns this question of 'usar' is "Hacer servir una cosa para algo".

Normally, when I'm in doubt about subtle differences between two synonyms I google them but I wasn't that lucky this time. Neither RAE, nor any other online dictionary could help me.

The sentence which I'm not sure about is:

> "[...] El nombre del archivo utilizado para este procedimiento es: hallarpi.m"

**Is this the right choice or should I have chosen 'usado'?**

I've deduced that 'utilizado' was the right choice out of intuition. I'd be grateful if someone could make clear the difference of them for this situation.

Comment: Both are the same, and another synonym is "emplear".

Comment: I really don't see much difference in meaning, except "utilizar" sounds a bit pretentious in most cases; almost like it often happens in English, when "utilize" is used instead of "use" (except in English, dictionaries seem to indicate that there's a specific meaning for "utilize" that does not exist for "use"; which doensn't happen in Spanish, to my knowledge)

Comment: It was used for an assignment so I think it's not pretentious in this case, but I would use 'usar' for casual conversations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Español

A pesar de que ambos son intercambiables en el uso común, creo que hay algunas importantes diferencias:

- Si no estoy equivocado, **utilizar** significa "lograr que algo sea útil", por lo que este verbo tiene un sentido más concreto que **usar**.

  - Quizá esta diferencia sea similar a la de los verbos ingleses **do** y **make**.
- A veces **usar** puede ser utilizado con un significado similar al inglés **to be used to** <sup>1</sup>:

  > **En ese tiempo se usaba poner nombres raros.**
  >   At that time it was used to strange names.
- Otra diferencia surge cuando nos referimos a las vestimentas: se puede usar el verbo **usar** para dar a entender **llevar puesta una ropa**, pero entonces no es tan común reemplazar **usar** por **utilizar**, porque corres el riesgo de dar a entender que usas esas prendas con un propósito diferente que "llevarlas puestas", por ejemplo si las usas para sacar lustre al piso (después de encerar):

  > **Estoy usando un chaleco.**
  >   I'm wearing a sweater.

  but:

  > **Estoy utilizando un chaleco.**
  >   I'm using a sweater (for some tacit purpose).

Pero es muy común en Español —para evitar repeticiones o cacofonías (algo muy importante en este idioma)— que cuando una oración debe usar el verbo **usar** (o **utilizar**) dos veces, entonces se reemplaza una de aquellas apariciones con el otro verbo:

> **El uso de esta herramienta es recomendable, no obstante utilícela con cuidado.**
>   The use of this tool is advisable, however use it with care.

Por lo tanto, respecto de tu ejemplo, yo preferiría esta frase:

> "[...] El nombre del archivo usado para este procedimiento es: hallarpi.m"

También es bueno recordar que hay otro verbo español con un significado similar: **emplear**.

---

## English

Despite both are usually interchangeable in the common usage, I think there are some important differences:

- As far as I know, **utilizar** means "make something useful", so it has a more "concrete" meaning than **usar**.

  - Perhaps this difference is similar to that of English verbs **do** and **make**.
- Sometimes **usar** may be used with a meaning similar to English **to be used to** <sup>1</sup>:

  > **En ese tiempo se usaba poner nombres raros.**
  >   At that time it was used to strange names.
- Another difference arises when referring to clothes: you may use **usar** in order to mean **wear**, but then it is not so common to replace **usar** with **utilizar**, because you may mean then that you use those clothes with a purpose different than "wearing them", for example if you used them to polish the floor:

  > **Estoy usando un chaleco.**
  >   I'm wearing a sweater.

  but:

  > **Estoy utilizando un chaleco.**
  >   I'm using a sweater (for some tacit purpose).

But it is very common in Spanish —in order to avoid repetition (something very important in that language)— that when a phrase or sentence must use **usar** (or **utilizar**) twice, then you replace one of those appearances with the other verb:

> **El uso de esta herramienta es recomendable, no obstante utilícela con cuidado.**
>   The use of this tool is advisable, however use it with care.

So, with your example, I would prefer this sentence:

> "[...] El nombre del archivo usado para este procedimiento es: hallarpi.m"

Also remember that there is another Spanish verb with a similar meaning: **emplear**.

---

1: http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?clave=usar&origen=RAE

Comment: I said that the only meaning I was interested about was the really similar to 'utilizar' one...
But your second point is great, I didn't think about it when I wondered why I preferred one over other and that could totally make it. Also for the comment from Juan Pablo Califano, that 'utilizar' is more formal.

Comment: The example "En ese tiempo se usaba poner nombres raros" is odd. What/who used to get those strange names? Additionally, the English translation ("At that time it was used to strange names") makes no sense. You probably meant something like "At that time people used to give strange names (to something/someone)".

Answer (score 4):

## Español

En general las dos palabras son sinónimos en el sentido de que las dos pueden significar "*a emplear algo a una meta específica*." ([utilizar - Wikcionario](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/utilizar#Espa.C3.B1ol) 1. y [usar - Wikcionario](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/usar#Espa.C3.B1ol) 1.)

Las mayores distinciones se encuentran en el uso regional y en las expresiones idiomáticas. También, el verbo `usar` me parece un poco más coloquial que el verbo `utilizar`, y se usa más en los contextos normales. Además, parace que la palabra `utilizar` tiene una distinción pequeña, en que la cosa utilizada probablemente se usa en una manera que normalmente no se usa, y para lograr algo diferente de lo que normalmente esta ordenado o a una ventaja.

> **Ejemplo coloquial:**
>
> A) *Voy a usar la estufa para preparar la comida.* => I will use the stove to prepare dinner.
>
> B) *Voy a utilizar el hornillo para preparar la comida.* => I will utilize the stove to prepare dinner.
>
> **Notas:**
>
> - Frase *A.* suena un poco más normal, pero, la frase *B*. es aceptable también.
>
> ---
>
> **Ejemplo de uso en una manera no normal:**
>
> *El agua puede existir en los tres estados de la materia en la temperatura ambiente, y por lo tanto, podemos utilizarla como refrigerante más fácilmente que el hidrógeno.* => Water can exist in the three states of matter at room temperature, therefore we can utilize it as a coolant easier than hydrogen.
>
> **Notas:**
>
> - En un caso come este, probablemente se puede usar el verbo `usar`, pero `utilizar` suena más apropiado.
>
> **Referencias:**
>
> - *"The Unusual Properties of Water Molecules." - For Dummies*. Web. 16 May 2012. <http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-unusual-properties-of-water-molecules.html>.

En la frase que usted menciona, yo personalmente usaria `usar` en lugar de `utilizar`, pero la frase parece correcta en las dos maneras.

---

## English

In general, the two words are pretty much synonyms, in the sense that both can mean "*to employ something to a specific goal*." (See: [utilizar - Wikcionario](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/utilizar#Espa.C3.B1ol) 1. & [usar - Wikcionario](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/usar#Espa.C3.B1ol) 1.)

The greatest distinctions are found mainly in regional usage, and in idiomatic expressions. The verb `usar` also seems a bit more colloquial than the verb `utilizar`, and is used more in normal contexts. On top of that, `utilizar` seems to have a slight nuance of the thing is probably being used in a way that it normally isn't, and to achieve a purpose it isn't normally ordained to or to an advantage.

> **Example of coloquial usage:**
>
> A) *Voy a usar la estufa para preparar la comida.* => I will use the stove to prepare dinner.
>
> B) *Voy a utilizar la estufa para preparar la comida.* => I will utilize the stove to prepare dinner.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - Sentence *A.* sounds a bit more normal, but, sentence *B*. is also acceptable.
>
> ---
>
> **Example of usage in terms beyond normal terms:**
>
> *El agua puede existir en los tres estados de la materia en la temperatura ambiente, y por lo tanto, podemos utilizarla como refrigerante más fácilmente que el hidrógeno.* => Water can exist in the three states of matter at room temperature, therefore we can utilize it as a coolant easier than hydrogen.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - Even in this case you probably could have used `usar`, but `utilizar` sounds a bit more natural.
>
> **References:**
>
> - *"The Unusual Properties of Water Molecules." - For Dummies*. Web. 16 May 2012. <http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-unusual-properties-of-water-molecules.html>.

Now, in the sentence you give, I personally would have used `usar` rather than `utilizar`, but it seems to be correct either way.

I hope I helped! :)

Comment: Great answer! But I don't think utilize and use can be literally translated to Spanish in this situation... Though I feel in the same way about the coloquial bit

Comment: "Usar" no es coloquial ni menos formal que "utilizar". Simplemente, "utilizar" es una palabra más larga que otorga pesadez a la expresión y resta elegancia. En textos científicos, hay quien siempre dice "utilizar", pero los manuales de estilo científico sugieren acertadamente sustituirlo por "usar", en aplicación del principio de concisión.

Comment: ¿Por qué resta elegancia? ¿Puedes poner algún link a algún manual de estilo científico en el que se especifique esto por favor?

Comment: "elegancia" es un concepto personal y subjetivo y por eso creo que no vale la pena discutirlo. Estoy de acuerdo que "utilizar" es *un poco* más formal que "usar", probablemente por ser una palabra más larga. Por último, no veo diferencia entre "usar" e "utilizar" en términos de como se usa el objeto (para lograr algo diferente de lo que normalmente está ordenado o no).

Answer (score 2):

Para mí, “usar” y “utilizar” son perfectos sinónimos en el sentido de “hacer servir una cosa para algo”. En mi opinión, “usar” es preferible en ese sentido, por pura economía lingüística. “Usar” da ligereza a las expresiones; “utilizar” suena cargado y rimbombante.

“Usar” es mejor palabra que “utilizar” por la misma razón que “influir” es mejor que “influenciar”, “ver” mejor que “visionar”, “devaluar” mejor que “desvalorizar”, “aclarar” mejor que “clarificar”, “impedir” mejor que “imposibilitar” y “contar” mejor que “contabilizar”.

Yo reservo “utilizar” para casos especiales, por ejemplo cuando nos referimos a personas (tiene entonces un matiz que lo aproxima a “manipular”).

Answer (score 1):

Otros detalles no comentados todavía...

Para decir que algo está gastado porque ha sido usado mucho se suele utilizar la palabra *usar*, como por ejemplo:

Voy a donar ropa *usada*. (ropa utilizada no quedaría bien).
La pieza está gastada por su *uso*.

Además, *utilizar* es una palabra más larga y posiblemente por ello se usa umenos utilizada en el lenguaje coloquial. En textos técnicos queda elegante y se mezclan ambas palabras para no repetir siempre la misma.